# How to do pagination in CnosDB?

Tags: database, cnosdb

There are some some concepts ([limit/offset/slimit/soffset](https://cnosdb.github.io/docs/content/cnosdb/latest/cnosql/cnosql_syntax.html)) in CnosDB similar to MySQL's limit/offset. I assume they could be used for pagination but I am really confused that why when I perform a query via limit 1, there are more than 1 result returned? Is this related to the series?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In CnosQL, you can use `LIMIT\SLIMIT\OFFSET\SOFFSET` in these cases:

- `LIMIT <N>` returns the first N points from the specified measurement.
- `SLIMIT <N>` returns every point from N series in the specified
  measurement.
- `OFFSET <N>` paginates N points in the query results.
- `SOFFSET <N>` paginates N series in the query results.

Compared with the SQL, there are several differences between CnosQL and SQL in the syntax of `LIMIT\SLIMIT\OFFSET\SOFFSET`.

In SQL, `LIMIT <N>` clause is used to limit the number of query results returned. It is often used for paginating queries.

In SQL, `OFFSET <N>` clause is used to skip N data and return the query results. As same as `LIMIT <N>`, `OFFSET <N>` is often used for paginating queries.

So, in order to understand the differences between CnosQL and SQL, we must make clear of some relative concept.

CnosDB is a time series database, which means the data restored is somewhat different from SQL databases. In short, CnosDB is made to store a large volume of time-series data and perform real-time analysis on those data, quickly.

The data in CnosDB is made up of `measurement`,`tag`,`field` and `timestamp`. Data points can have one of the fields on a measurement, all of the fields on a measurement, or any number in-between. You can understand these concepts by comparing with SQL.

- An CnosDB measurement is similar to an SQL database table.
- CnosDB tags are like indexed columns in an SQL database.
- CnosDB fields are like unindexed columns in an SQL database.
- CnosDB points are similar to SQL rows.

There are some concepts in CnosDB similar to SQL, but there also a new concept in CnosDB, `series`.

`series`, means a logical grouping of data defined by shared `measurement`, `tag set`, and `field key`.

SQL doesn't support the `SLIMIT <N>` clause and `SOFFSET <N>` clause, because the data in SQL doesn‘t have the concept of `series`.

There are many `series` in a CnosDB database. So the `SLIMIT\SOFFSET` clause is used to paginate `series` in result.

Click here for more information about the [CnosDB](https://www.cnosdb.com).